# Strcat is making my variable in loop change

Tags: c, string, strcat

I have come up with a serious problem. When I use `strcat` in the following C code, the value of `r` changes and the loop runs for an unexpected number of times. I am not able to figure out whats happening.
I have posted the code with the respective outputs.

`strcat` used:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
void scan_eqn (char *eqn)
{
    char temp[15] = "";
    int i, r;
    for (i = 0, r = 0; r < 11; r++, i++)
    {
        strcat (temp, eqn + i); 
        printf("r: %d ", r);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
} 

int main()
{
    char eq[50];
    printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", eq);
    scan_eqn(eq);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
abcdef
```

Output:

```
Enter the sentence: abcdef
r: 0 r: 1 r: 0 r: 1717920769
```

`strcat` not used:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
void scan_eqn (char *eqn)
{
    char temp[15] = "";
    int i, r;
    for (i = 0, r = 0; r < 11; r++, i++)
    {
        //strcat (temp, eqn + i); 
        printf("r: %d ", r);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
} 

int main()
{
    char eq[50];
    printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", eq);
    scan_eqn(eq);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
abcdef
```

Output:

```
Enter the sentence: abcdef
r: 1 r: 2 r: 3 r: 4 r: 5 r: 6 r: 7 r: 8 r: 9 r: 10
```

Comment: You write out of bounds of `temp`, causing undefined behaviour

Comment: Note that printing `r` in the loop is not very helpful — or insufficiently helpful.  It would be more sensible to print `temp`: `printf("r: %d [%s]\n", r, temp);`.  I prefer to see a newline at the end of a debugging `printf()` to help ensure the output appears timely.  On many systems, the output is line buffered so the data from `printf()` won't be flushed to the screen until a newline is printed, or you call `fflush(stdout)`, or the buffer (which is often quite big 512 to 4096 bytes) is full.

Comment: Aside:  `printf("r: %d ", r)` needs a `;`

Comment: Not only do you write out of bounds of the local variable `temp`, you also access beyond the end of the string passed as an argument to the function (after the seventh iteration when the input string is `absdef`).  Undefined behaviour is a serious problem, and reading or writing out of bounds is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @World Producer, Who or what test suggested `scanf("%[^\n]s", eq);` to read input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following illustrates how the buffer progresses toward overflow...

```
char temp[15] = "";
```

defines a space in memory that can contain 14 bytes of characters, and one `\0` if it is to be a string.   It conceptually looks like this:

```
|?|?|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|?|?|
    ^ temp starts here            ^ temp ends here
```

On the first iteration of the following loop:

```
for (i = 0, r = 0; r < 11; r++, i++)
{
    strcat (temp, eqn + i); 
    printf("r: %d ", r);
}
```

`temp` is populated with the contents of `eqn + i` -> `"abcdef"` ( `abcdef0` ) - showing null terminator)

```
|?|?|a|b|c|d|e|f|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|?|?|
```

On the 2nd iteration, `temp` is appended with the contents of
`eqn + i` -> `"bcdef"` ( `bcdef0` )

```
|?|?|a|b|c|d|e|f|b|c|d|e|f|0|0|0|0|?|?|
```

On the 3rd  iteration, `temp` is appended with the contents of
`eqn + i` -> `"cdef"` ( `cdef0` ) which overwrites the buffer `temp`

```
 |?|?|a|b|c|d|e|f|b|c|d|e|f|c|d|e|f|0|?|
                                   |^ buffer overflow  
                                   ^ temp ends here
```

This will *always* invoke [undefined behavior](https://www.opensourceforu.com/2018/10/understanding-undefined-behaviour-in-c/).

Here are a few suggestions to eliminate the magic numbers...  (See comments)

```
void scan_eqn (char *eqn)
{
    //char temp[100] = "";
    int i, r;
    int len = strlen(eqn);//get the length of input string
    //then size your input array accordingly using `sum of consecutive sequence` 
    size_t size = (len*(len + 1)/2) + 1;//adding one for final null terminator
    char temp[size]; //using VLA (Variable Length Array)
    memset(temp, 0, sizeof temp);//init all to null
    for (i = 0, r = 0; r < len; r++, i++)// replace magic number with len
    {
        strcat (temp, eqn + i); 
        printf("r: %d ", r);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

One additional suggestion.  In `main(void)`, make the following changes:

```
//scanf("%[^\n]s", eq);// replace this...
fgets(eq, sizeof eq, stdin);//with following two lines.   
eq[strcspn(eq, "\n")] = 0;//eliminate newline
```

Comment: Thanks ryyker for your reply. My code worked perfectly.

Comment: The step-by-step explanation is very well done.

Answer (score 3):

`strcat (temp, eqn + i);` is senseless for several reasons:

- You keep piling on strings to it, so it will first be `"abcdef"` then `"abcdefbcdef"`. It will quickly overflow.
- You don't check if there's anything left in `eqn` so after a certain number of iterations you access `eqn` beyond the end of the string.

I also don't understand what the magic number `r < 11` is supposed to do.